# Is it possible to play a music on one speaker and use headphones for online meeting on Mac?

Tags: mac, audio

I am trying to listen to music on YouTube through a Bluetooth speaker while also participating in a Zoom meeting using my headphones. However, I want to ensure that the music from YouTube is not played through my headphones and that the speech from the Zoom meeting is not played through the Bluetooth speaker.

I tried using the Audio MIDI Setup and created the Multi-Output device, but that only plays the same source on all output devices. I want to be able to choose which output is playing from which source.

Is it possible?

Comment: Control exactly where audio plays. Route music from one app to your best speakers, while everything else is heard via your Mac's built-in output. Can be done with https://rogueamoeba.com/soundsource/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SoundSource](https://rogueamoeba.com/soundsource/) allows application-specific audio routing, with all connected output devices as possible targets.

[image]